# How can I check new generated random in database and if it exists than again generate new in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

```
        var randnumber = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();
        
        bool CheckCaseRef = CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB(randnumber);
        
        if (CheckCaseRef)
        {
            randnumber = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();
        }
        else
        {
            randnumber = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();
        }
//Method to Check the generated random number 
        bool CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB(string randnumber)
        {
            Log.Info("CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB started...");
            bool checkCaseRef = false;
            try
            {
                var ObjCustomerList = db.tblCustomers.ToList();
                if (ObjCustomerList != null)
                {
                    foreach (var customerlst in ObjCustomerList)
                    {
                        if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(randnumber)))
                        {
                            if (customerlst.CaseRef == randnumber)
                            {
                                checkCaseRef = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return checkCaseRef;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error("Error CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB started...", ex);
                return false;
            }
            return checkCaseRef;
        }**
```

Comment: You're pulling the whole `tblCustomers` in a query which is inefficient. You're using Entity Framework right? Why not use `Where` Linq. And Do a Count SQL instead of pulling the whole data row.

Comment: Yes, I am using entity framework and if I use where than it will check the first one ... I want to check each generated random number

Answer (score 0):

Checking the regenerated one would be an excellent use for recursion. If you don't know much about recursion, I would highly recommend doing some research on it first though, as it can lead to some really nasty memory issues in your code if used incorrectly.

```
//Code in main method
string randnumber = CheckRandomNumber();

//Recursive method to call
public string CheckRandomNumber()
{
    string numToCheck = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();
    if (db.tblCustomers.Any(x => x.CaseRef == numToCheck))
    {
        //Duplicate was found
        CheckRandomNumber();
    }
    return numToCheck;
}
```

Comment: But sir in if part where I am generating the new one that one I also want to check .. how can I do that

Comment: But sir my question is in if condition where I am generating the second one how could I check that one ..that is the main issue ..for example as I have generated 1 and that exists in db that I create a new one like 2 that how can I check the 2 as well ..

Comment: See my latest edit to the answer. The solution you are looking for is a recursive method, or method that calls itself over and over until the requirements are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this:

```
var randnumber = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();

while (! CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB(randnumber))
{
    randnumber = CommonClass.Generate8DigitHBFNumber();
}
    
bool CheckCaseRefIdAlreadyExistsInDB(string randnumber)
{
    return db.tblCustomers.Any(c => c.CaseRef == randnumber ?? "");
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sylvain is it will check every newly generated as 1, 2,3. Etc

Comment: By the way, this is not really efficient and can lead to error, as your random number might be added to the database by another process between the time you checked its existence and the time you create your record. A sequence might help here.

Comment: Agreed up here, or A GUID